# submenu div issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am having a menu with sub menu.. this menu is coming from Data Base. on clink one of main menu a sub menu opens.. I want that when I click on any link of sub menu.. the sub menu remains open and the selected sub menu should remain selected. but problem is that when I click on any sub menu link.. I reached it's relevant link.. but sub menu get hide . I tried to using J-query to do so.. but failed due to loading new page... please tell me any way to do so..  now i want to use jquery or ajax solution of this

Comment: Got any code or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with you?

Comment: post the code that you have tried. So that we can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your problem i think this may help you.

- Use jQuery(include jQuery Library).
- On page you want to keep selected Main menu and submenu, Do the follwoing:

  1. Get Main menu and sub-menu ID and toggle it with jQuery.

> ```
>  $("#mainmenuid").toggle('fast');
>  $("#submenu").toggle('fast');
> ```

OR you can apply any jQuery events.

***Note:*** Add jQuery in the header area of that particular page page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$('#menu > li > a').click(function(){
    if($(this).siblings('ul').length > 0){
       $(this).siblings('ul').show();
       return false; // This will do what you want.
    }
});
```

This will not allow links if has any sibling "ul" elements. Otherwise, it will be go to it's href.

Test here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/SXKG4/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `load` if you want an ajax solution:

### suppose this is the html:

```
<ul id='main-menu'>
    <li><a href='pages/home.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='pages/about.html'>About us</a>
         <ul class='sub-menu'>           /*initially hide it display:none;*/
             <li><a href='pages/subpage1.html'>sub link 1</a></li>
             <li><a href='pages/subpage2.html'>sub link 2</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id='content'></div> <!--here you have to put page contents-->
```

### Then you can use this jQuery:

```
 $(function(){
    $('#main-menu li').click(function(){
       var page = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
       $('#content').load(page);
       $('.submenu',this).toggle();
    });

     $('#main-menu a').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault(); // <-----this stops page to navigate to link href
     });

    $('.submenu li').click(function(ev){
       ev.stopPropagation(); //<----stops the event bubbling to the parent
    });
 });
```